# Understanding of Begininvoke args in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, begininvoke

I use to browse this forum to find answers but this time I just couldn't figure out anything that would make me completely understand the following question.

I've got this program :

```
IAsyncResult asrr;
        DELG d = (o) =>
        {
            short i = 10;
            string msg = (string)o;
            while (i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Work - > {0}::{1}", i, msg);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i--;
            }
        };
        asrr = d.BeginInvoke(((object)("T1")), (asr) =>
        {
            DELG dlg = (DELG)((System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)asr).AsyncDelegate;
            dlg.EndInvoke(asr);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("callback");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }, d);
```

Then I think I understood what's happening here : We have a delegate that is asynchronously called using asrr. We give the delegate 'd' several args : T1, which will be displayed in the delegate, a callback methode (I'm using a lambda methode because this was requiered in this exercice) and d, the delegate.

Well I don't really get it... I understand we send T1 but where comes "(asr)" from ? I don't get anything that is happening after the begininvoke nor what does :

```
DELG dlg = (DELG)((System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)asr).AsyncDelegate;
```

Here again I can see the asr but don't understand it.

I've found this link :
[Delegates and Events](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Delegates_and_Events%E2%80%94Asynchronous_method_calls)
But even though it helped me, I still don't get the whole of it.
Would you please provide me some information about it ?

Thanks a lot to the incoming answers.

Comment: Once you find the answer, please mark it as answer. So that others can use it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add further to others' answers.

This is Asynchronous call.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/2e08f6yc.aspx) ,

The `BeginInvoke` method initiates the asynchronous call. It has the same parameters as the method that you want to execute asynchronously, plus two additional optional parameters. The first parameter is an `AsyncCallback` delegate that references a method to be called when the asynchronous call completes. The second parameter is a user-defined object that passes information into the callback method. `BeginInvoke` returns immediately and does not wait for the asynchronous call to complete. `BeginInvoke` returns an `IAsyncResult`, which can be used to monitor the progress of the asynchronous call.

The `EndInvoke` method retrieves the results of the asynchronous call. It can be called any time after `BeginInvoke`. If the asynchronous call has not completed, `EndInvoke` blocks the calling thread until it completes. The parameters of `EndInvoke` include the `out` and `ref` parameters `(<Out> ByRef and ByRef in Visual Basic)` of the method that you want to execute asynchronously, plus the `IAsyncResult` returned by `BeginInvoke`

Look at the link for further info.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was waiting for.
Thank you very much for being that clear and for your time !

Comment: I'm glad, you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the `asr` in the `BeginInvoke` call - the part that has `(asr) =>` is the declaration. The type is inferred.

Comment: I think what he's asking about is where the value of **asr** comes from.

Answer (score 0):

`asr` is the input parameter for your anonymous delegate.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx for more information.

the delegate has a signature with one input parameter. you declare the input parameter to be referred as `asr` in the function block between the braces.

Comment: Thank you for these information. But isn't this input parameter the "((object)("T1"))" That is just before ? So I understood that asr get created directly when being assigned the lambda function but to me it seems like a 2nd parameter sent to the delegate.